# React native events fail to emit when called from IntentService

Tags: android, react-native

For some reason when emitting an event via an `IntentService` nothing happens on the Javascript side. Here's what I'm doing:

1. Create an `IntentService` with an `onHandleIntent` method like so:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable final Intent intent) {
     if (intent != null) {
       logger.info("Broadcasting event");
       intent.setAction(ACTION);
       LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
     }
   }
   ```
2. Register the `IntentService` to the `com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingClient`:

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent(getReactApplicationContext().getBaseContext(), BoundaryEventIntentService.class);
   this.mBoundaryPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getReactApplicationContext().getBaseContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.
           FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
   ```
3. Create the `BroadcastReceiver` for the `IntentService` to broadcast messages to:

   ```
   public class GeofenceEventBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
       if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
           // handle errors
       }
       switch (geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition()) {
           case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER:
               Log.i(TAG, "Enter geofence event detected. Sending event.");
               WritableArray writableArray = Arguments.createArray();
               for (Geofence geofence : geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences()) {
                   writableArray.pushString(geofence.getRequestId());
               }
               sendEvent(ON_ENTER, writableArray);
               break;
           // handle other events e.g. GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT
         }
      }
   }
   ```
4. And finally my `sendEvent` method:

   ```
   private void sendEvent(String event, Object params) {
     Log.i(TAG, "Sending events " + event);
     getReactApplicationContext()
         .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
         .emit(event, params);
     Log.i(TAG, "Sent events");
   }
   ```

My `BroadcastReceiver` is an inner class on my `ReactContextBaseJavaModule` so it has access to my react application context and the `sendEvent` method. Everything triggers successfully except the javascript side of this does not receive the event. I realize this is quite a bit of code and I may not have included all of the needed context. The library can be found [here](https://github.com/eddieowens/react-native-boundary) if more context is needed.

Answer (score 1):

A possible reason would be you are using intent service, which will be affected by doze mode. Update to use Job Intent Service instead of intent service.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/JobIntentService

Android background location limits
In order to preserve battery, user experience, and system health, background apps receive location updates less frequently when used on a device running Android 8.0. This behavior change affects all apps that receive location updates, including Google Play services.

These changes affect the following APIs:

Fused Location Provider (FLP)
Geofencing
GNSS Measurements
Location Manager
Wi-Fi Manager

Read this link for changes that are done in 8.0

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes

**Note:** IntentService is a service, and is therefore subject to the new restrictions on background services. As a result, many apps that rely on IntentService do not work properly when targeting Android 8.0 or higher. For this reason, Android Support Library 26.0.0 introduces a new JobIntentService class, which provides the same functionality as IntentService but uses jobs instead of services when running on Android 8.0 or higher.